# Extend filter_horizontal in django admin

Tags: python, django, filter, admin

I have django app (django 1.11) and I need to extend filter_horizontal. I mean, I need to near title also a date of event.

Here is my first model, where is M2M to event:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    events = models.ManyToManyField('events.Event', related_name="products", blank=True)
```

admin.py, and here I would like to have event title and date of event (event_title - event_date). Is it possible?

```
class ProductAdmin(TranslationAdmin):
    list_display = ('title',)
    filter_horizontal = ('events',)
```

here is model of event:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateField()
```